# How to organize frontend and backend for Kotlin SPA with Webpack

Tags: gradle, webpack, kotlin, single-page-application

I am developing an SPA with Kotlin (Ktor) on the backend. The project structure now is:

```
.
├── frontend/                <-- SPA frontend source project
│   ├── dist/                <-- current webpack dist
│   ├── node_modules/        <-- not to be included in the jar
│   ├── src/                 <-- to be bundled by webpack
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── index.html           <-- to be served as static by backend
│   ├── package.json         <-- not to be included in the jar
│   └── webpack.config.json  <-- not to be included in the jar
│
├── src/                     <-- SPA backend source
|   └── main/
|       ├── kotlin/
|       |   └── Main.kt      <-- backend entry point
|       └── resources/       <-- framework-specific configuration
│
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

The frontend successfully compiles with `cd frontend && npm run build`, storing the resulting bundle into the `frontend/dist`.

Ktor routing setup:

```
fun Application.main() {
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)

    routing {
        static("/") {
            default("frontend/index.html") // to be replaced with index file
                                           // from packaged frontend
        }
        // ... other dynamic routes for REST
    }
}
```

build.gradle is pretty standard:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ext.ktor_version = '0.9.2'
    ext.koin_ktor_version = '0.9.2'
    ext.ktor_gson_version = '0.9.2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group 'org.root_talis'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'MainKt'

kotlin { experimental { coroutines "enable" } }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-gson:$ktor_gson_version"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.1"
    compile "org.koin:koin-ktor:$koin_ktor_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

How do I make Gradle compile the frontend project through `npm run build` and package the `dist` into the resulting JAR for it to be served by the backend?

Are there any recommendations on organizing such projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run some `npm` commands you can either install Node on the machine you are working on, declare an `Exec` task and make the `build` task depend on it.

```
val npmBuilder by tasks.creating(Exec::class){
    // some stuff
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(npmBuilder)
```

Have a look at the documention of the `Exec` task [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).

Otherwise you could apply [this Node plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) allowing you not to depend from the machine setup.

Furthermore I'd recommend to handle the routes of your SPA not by hand but using [this Ktor Feature](https://github.com/lamba92/ktor-spa)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this project: https://github.com/yole/kxhtml-isomorphic
and read http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html#multiplatform-projects